# SCSS mixin for CSS animations outputting variable names in CSS

Tags: sass, mixins

I am trying these SCSS mixins [from this gist](https://gist.github.com/Integralist/3931680) for CSS animation browser prefixes, but it's outputting the literal `$animation_name` where it should be outputting the actual value for `$animation_name` in the CSS. How do I get the actual value into the CSS output?

SCSS:

```
@mixin animation ($delay, $duration, $animation) {
-webkit-animation-delay: $delay;
-webkit-animation-duration: $duration;
-webkit-animation-name: $animation;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

-moz-animation-delay: $delay;
-moz-animation-duration: $duration;
-moz-animation-name: $animation;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 

-o-animation-delay: $delay;
-o-animation-duration: $duration;
-o-animation-name: $animation;
-o-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 

animation-delay: $delay;
animation-duration: $duration;
animation-name: $animation;
animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}

@mixin mykeyframe ($animation_name) {
  @-webkit-keyframes $animation_name {
      @content;
  }

  @-moz-keyframes $animation_name {
      @content;
  }

  @-o-keyframes $animation_name {
      @content;
  }

  @keyframes $animation_name {
      @content;
  }
}

.top{
  position:relative;
  top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  @include animation(0s,1s,inFromTop);
}

@include mykeyframe(inFromTop) {
  from{
    margin-top: -100%;
  }
  to{
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

CSS output (note the literal `$animation_name` in the code)

```
.top {
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-name: inFromTop;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
  -moz-animation-name: inFromTop;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -o-animation-delay: 0s;
  -o-animation-duration: 1s;
  -o-animation-name: inFromTop;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: inFromTop;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes $animation_name {
  from {
    margin-top: -100%;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes $animation_name {
  from {
    margin-top: -100%;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes $animation_name {
  from {
    margin-top: -100%;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes $animation_name {
  from {
    margin-top: -100%;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

Here's the [HTML and SCSS in Codepen](https://codepen.io/mrengy/pen/aVXLoO?editors=1100)

Inspect the CSS in [Codepen debug mode](https://s.codepen.io/mrengy/debug/aVXLoO/vPMKKVDVyEBM) to see the CSS it is outputting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Sass interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Interpolation_____) seems to solve the issue: [SassMeister Demo](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/9b68d7faf8c1d5ef0ff1f817de50a5a6)

SCSS:

```
@mixin mykeyframe ($animation_name) {
  @-webkit-keyframes #{$animation_name} {
      @content;
  }

  @-moz-keyframes #{$animation_name} {
      @content;
  }

  @-o-keyframes #{$animation_name} {
      @content;
  }

  @keyframes #{$animation_name} {
      @content;
  }
}
```

CSS Output:

```
@-webkit-keyframes inFromTop {
  from {
    margin-top: -100%;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes inFromTop {
  from {
    margin-top: -100%;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes inFromTop {
  from {
    margin-top: -100%;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes inFromTop {
  from {
    margin-top: -100%;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```